# Elasticsearch suggest function with like in prefix

Tags: elasticsearch, autosuggest, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-mapping

I have an index with some name stored in.

```
PUT localhost:9200/myIndex
{
  "mappings": {
    "record" : {
      "properties" : {
        "namesuggest" : {
          "type" :     "completion"
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

So I entered some records:

```
PUT localhost:9200/myindex/record/1
{
  "namesuggest" : "Homer Simpson"
}

PUT localhost:9200/myindex/record/2
{
   "namesuggest" : "Bart Simpson"
}

    PUT localhost:9200/myindex/record/3
{
  "namesuggest" : "Marge Simpson"
}
```

With this query I get the suggestions:

```
POST localhost:9200/myindex/_search
{
    "suggest": {
        "name-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "bart",
            "completion" : {
                  "field" : "namesuggest"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I set `prefix == bart` I have returned the suggestion "Bart Simpson" and it's correct.

I don't understand why, if I set `prefix == Simpson` I have returned blank results.

I would have a result set that match `%Simpson%` with SQL like operator:

- Homer Simpson
- Bart Simpson
- Marge Simpson

  How can I do the query?

Comment: because Simpson is a suffix. If you need fast, indexed suffix search, the recommended trick is to add a multi-field to your mapping which includes a reverse token filter https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-reverse-tokenfilter.html . Then you can run prefix queries on that reversed field and essentially get suffix search in an optimized manner.

Comment: can you get me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Completion suggestion works on an FST and it's implementation is optimized for prefixes.

And since the string "Bart Simpson" doesn't start with "Simpson" it won't match.

However, you can use an analyzer which will store the tokens in reverse. I.e. 
"Bart Simpson" => [Simpson,Bart]. Then when you search for Simpson, it does match the prefix.

References: https://www.elastic.co/assets/bltced6bd71d5fa33ab/suggest_1.png?uid=bltced6bd71d5fa33ab